# Как сделать копирование и вставку строк таблицы для дерева?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Имеется таблица базы данных.
На основании таблицы формируется дерево.
Поле `ID` автоинкремент (формируется базой данных).

Сценарий:

1. Пользователь. Выбирает узел, **который** нужно копировать;
2. Пользователь. Выбирает узел **куда** нужно копировать;
3. Приложение. Получает строку узла, который нужно копировать;
4. Приложение. Копирует строку `DataTable` и связанные с ней строки в качестве дочерних строк (узлов) в узел, который указан как "получатель";
5. Приложение. Обновляет таблицу базы данных на основании изменений `DataTable`.

**Вопрос.**
 Как выполнить программно "копировать" и "вставить" для определённой записи таблицы(`DataTable`) и её дочерних узлов(строк) и чтобы копирование применялось для узлов различной степени вложенности?
 В вопросе имеется ввиду как выполнить п.3, п.4.

Результат копирования должен привести к тому, 
что в DataTable появятся дополнительные строки:
**ID // PrID // sorting // NodeName // field_1 // field_2 // field_3**
18 16 0 AA Node Level_2
19 18 0 AAA Node Level_3
20 19 0 AAAA Node Level_4
21 19 1 AAAB Node Level_4
23 19 2 AAAC Node Level_4_Изм_3

**Код подключения**

```
public void connect()
        {
            string catBD = @"c:\test\visualStudio\csharp\01\01.accdb";
            string conBD = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", catBD);

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conBD);

            connection.Open();

            string query1 = "SELECT * FROM TableTreeView_12_0";
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, connection);


            dt = new DataTable();

            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
            cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.Fill(dt);

        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Исходная таблица**
**ID // PrID // sorting // NodeName // field_1 // field_2 // field_3**
1   0   0   A Node Level_1_изм_2
2   1   0   AA Node  Level_2
3   2   0   AAA Node Level_3
4   3   0   AAAA Node Level_4
5   3   1   AAAB Node Level_4
6   3   2   AAAC Node  Level_4_Изм_3
7   1   1   AB Node Level_2
8   1   2   AC Node Level_2
9   0   1   B Node  Level_1
10  9   0   BA Node  Level_2
11  9   1   BB Node  Level_2
12  9   2   BC Node  Level_2
13  0   2   C Node  Level_1
14  13  0   CA Node  Level_2
15  13  1   CB Node  Level_2
16  13  2   CC Node  Level_2
17  13  3   CD Node  Level_2

Comment: В чем у вас проблема? Как это сделать визуально? Или как поменять в базе? из вопроса не понятно.

Comment: вы хотите перенести дочерние элементы  одно родителя в другой родитель перетаскиванием мыши?

Comment: @АлексейЛосев Обновил вопрос. Мне удалось сформулировать более корректно?

Comment: @Санитариум Обновил вопрос. Мне удалось сформулировать вопрос более корректно?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо у копируемой строки изменить "Pr ID" с 1 на 16. Ну это если говорить про ваш пример. В общем случае изменить у копируемой строки атрибут "Pr ID" на значение атрибута первичного ключа (атрибут ID) строки в которую вы копируете. После этого вызвать сохранение данных.

```
static void CopyNode(DataRow selecttedRow, DataRow targetRow)
{
    selecttedRow["Pr ID"] = targetRow["ID"];
}
```

Ну и вызываете сохранение данных из адаптера в базу.

Comment: Немного не то... Обновил вопрос. Я устно смутно представляю как сделать, а как кодом это сделать, что-то не пойму

Comment: Добавил код. Т.к. это дерево, то на уровне базы вам достаточно поменять родителя у одного элемента, чтобы все поддерево переехало в новый элемент.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то работает для одной строки. Например - `2 1 0 AA Node Level_2` (для той с которой начинается копирование), а как в дочерних изменить `Pr ID`? Чтобы по цепочке прошло изменение... PS Я начинающий. Прошу извинить если вопрос некорректен

Comment: Я же вам написал, надо изменить родителя только у одной строки. Все остальные как были привязаны к строке с Id равным 2 (в вашем примере) так и остаются. У вас поддерево переехало из одного узла в другое. Для этого достаточно перенести только узел.